# Derivative rules: Constant rule, is it 0 or 1?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, constants

Because of the constant rule, $\frac{d}{dx}(k) = 0$, where k is any constant.
[image]

However in one of the practice problems:
Differentiate integer powers (mixed positive and negative), I tried to apply the same and $\frac{d}{dx}(x) = 1$ instead of zero.

Can someone explain to me why it is 1 instead of 0 here?

[image]

Comment: $x$ is not constant

Comment: When they say $d/dx(k) = 0$ the assumption is $k$ is a constant, i.e. a number like 7 or 45, not some variable, say $x$ or $\theta$ (for which we do not know an explicit value). So $d/dx(7) = 0$ (it's a constant, unchanging number) while $d/dx(x) = 1$, it's a function, its values can change (and azif does into good detail exactly how you can calculate $d/dx(x)$).

Comment: It (also) helps to attack the question with your intuition.  If you have a function $f(x)$ and you graph it, then $f'(x)$ represents the *slope* of $f(x)$.  Graph the following functions separately, and ask yourself, with each function, what is it's slope, as a function of $x$: (1) $f(x) = x$, (2) $f(x) = 2x$, (3) $f(x) = 5$, (4) $f(x) = x^2.$

Comment: Gotcha, of course. It's because it is not constant! Sorry, that didn't click in my brain. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a derivative here is: $n \cdot x ^{n-1}$.

Example: $f(x) = x^2$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2), n=2 \\ \text{applying the definition of the derivative} \\ n \cdot x ^{n-1} = 2x^{2-1} = 2x^1 = 2x \\ \text{Now apply this rule to the variable in your question} \\ \frac{d}{dx}(x), \text{where $x = x^1$} \\ n = 1, n \cdot x ^{n-1} = 1 \cdot x ^0 = 1$$

The main point, $x$ is a variable. If $x$ was defined as a constant than it would be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A constant function $f(x) = c$ means at any value of $x$, $f(x)  = c$. $F(x)=x$ is a linear not a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac d{dx}(x) = \frac d{dx}(x^1) = 1 \cdot x^{1-1} = x^0 = 1.$$